# Unable to connect to Azure data lake store via SSIS

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-lake

I have been trying to connect my SSIS package (on prem) to connect to my data lake store. I have installed the Azure Feature pack which has worked fine.
But when I create a Data Lake connection in my ssis package, I need the following .

[Image of SSIS Azure Data Lake connector Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEicO.png)

ADLS Host – which is fine I know how to get that.

Authentication ( Azure AD User Identity )

UserName & Password, - which I am having issues with.

My question is how do I define a username and password for my data lake?

Answer (score 1):

You can find them in Azure AD User which is within the same subscription with your Azure Data Lake. Usually, it is your email address and password which you used to login Azure portal.

[image]

More details, you can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/azure-data-lake-store-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver15#configure-the-azure-data-lake-store-connection-manager).